# Why does Ubuntu 18.04 uefi boot cause kernel freeze?

Tags: kernel, uefi, freeze

I've just bought a new AMD Ryzen/Radeon notebook (Acer Aspire 3) and I wanted to install a Kubuntu 18.04 on it. I checked the bios settings and uefi was the only boot option, so there is no legacy mode what I had used with my old computer before. 
I downloaded the normal iso image and made an usb boot pendrive using mkusb.
The boot was okay, I got an uefi type menu but after starting the kernel it paniced(?) instantly.
Error messages: ACPI Error [MAC0] Namespace lookup failure
ACPI ERROR 1 table load failures, 13 successful
BUG: soft lockup CPU#0 stuck for 22s

I tried to boot the same pendrive on my girlfriend's Travelmate which has a legacy/compatible boot mode and it freezes using uefi but works well  with legacy mode.

Comment: Unless there's maybe something wrong with your USB such that the UEFI bits are in a bad sector of the flash, I don't really see how the same USB on legacy would work any differently. It's the same kernel in both cases. There could of course be some bug in the kernel, but it's really not possible to say what exactly happened with your install. Maybe try a stock Ubuntu 18.04 ISO instead of Kubuntu, to see if it will work better?

Comment: Hi, now I think maybe it is an amd kernel module error, couldn't you help me to debug it?

Comment: AskUbuntu is not a good venue for such lengthy discussions. I'd suggestion opening a bug report at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/ perhaps to get some help from the developers in debugging. I can say that 18.04 boots just fine (and works pretty great) on both my Ryzen systems though (but neither is a laptop).